# How to set layout of custom list view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create custom list view in my app. In portrait it is fine but in landscape mode the width of the row remains same as in portrait.Here is the screen shot of list  and code i am using to create the list view.[image]

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/lnrRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/textlines" >

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_Profile_Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

 </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/lnrRowAction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button 
     android:id="@+id/imgEdit"
     style="@style/editButton"  />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/imgDelete"
        style="@style/deleteButton" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

   <style name="editButton">
        <item name="android:drawableLeft">@drawable/ic_action_edit</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/Gray</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
          <item name="android:background">@color/Transparent</item>
        <item name="android:text">Edit</item>
   </style>
```

Comment: Can we see the editButton and deleteButton styles?

Comment: @s1m3n i have edit the code here is the style for edit button

Comment: Maybe you can use compound drawables http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableBottom instead of linear layout with only one textview child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could point you to the right direction (if you don't set a weight and/or a width in your button styles):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnrRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_Profile_Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@drawable/textlines"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imgEdit"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="@style/editButton"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imgDelete"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="@style/deleteButton"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this will add divider line thru out row but  i dnt need it under action buttons.

Comment: I then moved the background from the LinearLayout to the TextView, so only that will be underlined.

Answer (score 1):

Use Relative Layout instead of Linear Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/lnrRow"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_Profile_Name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/imgEdit"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgEdit"
    android:background="@drawable/textlines" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/imgEdit"
    style="@style/editButton"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/imgDelete"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgDelete" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/imgDelete"
    style="@style/deleteButton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because in your parent Linear Layout the orintation is ***horizontal***. So just you have to change it by ***vertical*** and get your desired layout..